# defaulting output behavior to print in ipython console

Tags: printing, output, ipython, spyder, qtconsole

What setting in spyder should I change such that when I submit this code, I get identical looking output for both print call ?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4]})
df.shape
print df.shape
```

I suspect that `df.shape` isn't exactly the same as `print df.shape` but on any other installation of Spyder that I have used, both call behave the same. I am using python 2.7.12, conda 4.1.11 and pandas 0.18.1

Currently `print df.shape` correctly prints the shape of df in the console. `df.shape` is displaying the shape of df in a bigger and dark font in the console.

A picture is worth a 1000 words, what I am getting currently looks like this:
[image]